# How to submit application to app store from another account?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store

I'm new ios developer I submitted few personal apps to app store.

I'm facing new experiment to update an external app to app store. I have all required information to login.

I need the steps to do it successfully from my macOS without got block or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable to have more than one account registered with Xcode.

Open Xcode Preferences->Accounts and click the `+` at the bottom of the "Apple IDs" table to add a new account.

Alternatively you could ask the owner of the external app to invite your personal Apple ID as a team member. Your personal team & external team will show up separately under the Xcode account preferences.

Once the Apple ID is registered with Xcode you can build/sign/submit as normal.

Comment: Did you know how to make the 2 fact auth in other mac device ?

Comment: As far I recall, you can create a new user account on the mac, to use just for 2 factor auth. What I tend to do is set the 2 factor auth up and then use my phone number to receive the code (you can use the same phone number for multiple Apple accounts) by clicking "Didn’t get a verification code?" and choosing SMS